# How to read an array of hashes as parameter in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wanna read an array of hashes as parameter from postman (or anything else).
**postman**:

```
{
  "domains": [
     {"id":"1", "name": "aa"},
     {"id":"2", "name": "bb"}
  ]

}
```

I need to read this parameter exactly like this:
**ruby on rails**:

```
 [
     {"id":"1", "name": "aa"},
     {"id":"2", "name": "bb"}
 ]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What is context? Is the first codeblock the JSON body (with `Content-Type: application/json`) of a POST request? If so have you tried accessing it using `params[:domains]` in the controller?

Comment: yes, It is. but with ```params[:domains]```, I receive ``` [<ActionController::Parameters {"id"=>"1", "name"=>"aaa"} permitted: false>]```. but I need to read exactly like my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can permit your params with this syntax.

```
params.permit(:domains: %i[id name])
```

Comment: See: [Action Controller Overview - 4.5 Strong Parameters](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters)